# FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations

Tags: flutter

i added firebase auth and Firebase Analytics to flutter project after that its showing some kind of warning  in debug console
**Warning :**

```
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_analytics-9.3.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\analytics\FlutterFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-3.7.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\auth\FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

i have no idea what's this
will i face some kind of issue because of this or should leave it like this?

**pubspec.yaml file**

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

 cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^1.21.1
  firebase_auth: ^3.7.0
  firebase_analytics: ^9.3.3
  cloud_firestore: ^3.4.6

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

 flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try sdk: `'>=2.11.0 <3.0.0'` instead of sdk: `'>=2.18.0 <3.0.0'`
and then do `flutter clean` in terminal

Answer (score 0):

You will not face any error, just update your dependencies when an update comes :)

Comment: all dependencies are up to date